# 'DROP' table inside trigger - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'chat_record' which has a column 'chat_id'. For each 'chat_id' there exists table of same name. Now i Want to create a trigger to drop the table whenever an entry from chat_record is deleted.
Here is my code -
**

```
create trigger drop_table before delete on chat_record
for each row
begin
declare chatid varchar(20);
set @chatid=(select chat_id from chat_record where chat_id=old.chat_id);
drop table chatid;
end;
```

**
Error 1422 : Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed is stored function or trigger.

Comment: Please don't do that. Imagine the confusion for anyone trying to mainatain the code. Oh, the table goes away sometimes - I have no idea why? May I suggest that you explain what requirement you had that lead you to doing that as an answer? i.e. You don't want to create a triigger solve the problem - you want to solve the problem in an easy to understand and test approach? You tried it using a trigger - it is not as reliable as you wish?

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger drop_table1 before delete on chat_record
for each row
declare
chatid1 varchar(20);
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
select 1 into chatid1 from chat_record where chat_id=:old.chat_id;
if chatid1 = 1
then
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table chatid';
end if;
end;
```